# Vim "* and "+ in screen

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I recently started using screen, and I am enjoying it quite a bit. The problem is, when I run vim from within screen, I can no longer seem to access the + register.

It used to be, I could say

```
"+dd
```

to cut a line to the system clipboard, and then paste it somewhere else. But running vim within screen, `"+dd` no longer seems to pull to the system clipboard.

Does anyone know how to address this?

Comment: I think you mean "system clipboard" rather than "system keyboard".

Comment: You don't specify whether you run screen locally or remotely in an ssh session. In a remote session you can only interact with the X server (and hence the X11 clipboard) when forwarding X connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's called "clipboard". (The keyboard is [something else.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10vMd.jpg))

The `"+` and `"*` registers correspond to X11 'clipboard' and 'primary' selections, and require access to the X11 server. It could be that Screen is removing this access somehow.

1. Make sure the **display address** is correct.

   Compare the output of `:echo $DISPLAY` in Vim *inside* Screen with the output of `printenv DISPLAY` in a shell *outside* Screen.
2. Make sure you have access to the correct **authorization data** file, Xauthority.

   Again, compare `:echo $XAUTHORITY` in Vim+Screen with `echo $XAUTHORITY` in bash outside Screen. (It is okay if both values are empty; however, they must not be different from each other.)
3. Try adding yourself to the **access list** using `xhost +si:localuser:$USER` from a working terminal window.
4. Try running `:!xsel -o` or `:!xdpyinfo` inside Vim+Screen and **look for any error messages**.

Comment: Is it bad if I knew what the image was by looking at the link?

Comment: So if $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY are empty, and steps 3 and 4 both give errors about being unable to open the display (there is no x session running on the machine), is there a way to resolve this - or is the idea of a "system clipboard" something only provided by X11?

Comment: @SteveKroon: Right, there is no such thing as "system clipboard". [If anything, there would be a _session_ clipboard – remember that the OS is multi-user.] It is provided by the X11 server, separately for each display. Without X11 or Wayland, terminal-based programs only have their own private buffers; while it is technically possible to implement a shared buffer (e.g. shm), there haven't been _any_ attempts to define a standard one.